# What is the most feasible way to store large array data while being able to access it from a web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, json, database

I have come across many ways to do this, but, either a third party resource is needed or the solution is not practical to implement.

What I need to store is an immense amount of data (an array with 700 nested arrays and 10 entries in each array). Some methods I've thought of are listed below together with their drawbacks:

1. Using JSON:
   It's just a lot of work on the browser. The browser will freeze when I loop through the array.
2. Using an SQL database
   I won't be able to run my webpage in any computer. I will have to install PHP and SQL in every computer I wish to run my webpage in.
3. Using a C++ program to handle the heavy work
   This will only work with chrome, where I can use the file system API.

Note: the webpage won't be uploaded to the internet.

What would be best to do in this situation?

Comment: 700*10 isnt that much, if you encouter a "freeze" while iterating over it you should maybe show the code

Comment: I didn't encounter a freeze; I just assumed this will happen in a slow PC (like mine), because I once tried creating table rows using javascript and I encountered freezes.

Comment: i am pretty sure if you can find a 20 years old pc it will have no problem to handle a 7000 elements array (assuming you dont store 100Mb objects in it ;)

Comment: An array of 700 elements is peanuts for any browser, including IE. I can show you tables with 100k rows rendering and scrolling smoothly. Most likely, your problems lie with generating HTML elements from that data in a way that, most likely, burdens the browser unnecessarily. Without providing a [mcve] you can't get much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexDB was designed for your purpose:

> IndexedDB is a low-level API for client-side storage of significant
>   amounts of structured data, including files/blobs. This API uses
>   indexes to enable high-performance searches of this data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

And here are some great examples of use:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API#Examples

Comment: I am not familiar with IndexDB. If I implement it, will I encounter the same problem as the database, i.e. can I run the webpage in any computer without installing a third party component?

Comment: Yes - indexDB is part of the browser, built in. But be warned: https://caniuse.com/#search=indexed